# How can i make fancybox display a "yes/no confirm box" via a href onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

im using the following code as replacements for confirm boxes in javascript.

```
    function fancyAlert(msg) {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'modal' : true,
        'content' : "<div style=\"margin:1px;width:240px;\">"+msg+"<div style=\"text-align:right;margin-top:10px;\"><input style=\"margin:3px;padding:0px;\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"jQuery.fancybox.close();\" value=\"Ok\"></div></div>"        });    }

function fancyConfirm(msg, callback) {
    var ret;
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'modal' : true,
        'content' : "<div style=\"margin:1px;width:240px;\">"+msg+"<div style=\"text-align:right;margin-top:10px;\"><input id=\"fancyConfirm_cancel\" style=\"margin:3px;padding:0px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\"><input id=\"fancyConfirm_ok\" style=\"margin:3px;padding:0px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"Ok\"></div></div>",
        onComplete : function() {
            jQuery("#fancyConfirm_cancel").click(function() {
                ret = false;
                jQuery.fancybox.close();
            })
            jQuery("#fancyConfirm_ok").click(function() {
                ret = true;
                jQuery.fancybox.close();
            })
        },
        onClosed : function() {
            if (typeof callback == 'function'){ callback.call(this, ret); };
        }
    });
}

function fancyConfirm_text() {
    fancyConfirm("Ceci est un test", function(ret) {
        alert(ret)
    })
}
```

and im using a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="fancyConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");">Test</a>
```

im stuck, it just wont display anything?, i think its got something to do with the callback variable required for fancyConfirm but im unsure what that means and how it applies.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your link attribute. You can't place double-quotes inside of double-quotes without escaping them. Right now, your onclick attribute is just: "fancyConfirm("

Try:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="fancyConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">Test</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="fancyConfirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete?\");">Test</a>
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake on my part, i already have the single quotes in place yet it still doesnt work? , any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need this instead:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fancyConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');return false;">Test</a>
```

That should work. The hash (#) wont show in the URL because `return false;` will only make what is in the `onclick` happen.

Also, I know this is obvious, but do you have Fancybox and jQuery defined on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post,

[Javascript/Jquery Callback for Fancybox Yes No Confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10446122/186896)

The author of fancy box has a slightly different solution and it works.