# Extend Javascript Confirm Box with fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I extended all my `alert` with fancybox like this

```
window.alert = function(message){
    $("#alert_message_box .warmsg span").html(message);
    $.fancybox({'href':'#alert_message_box'});
    return false;
}
```

and its working fine. I also try to extend `confirm` box like

```
 window.confirm = function(message){
    $("#confirm_message_box .warmsg span").html(message);
    $.fancybox({'href':'#confirm_message_box'});
}
```

`confirm_message_box` div contain two buttons, `Yes` and `No`.

`if(confirm(alert_msg)){
}`
In this case how the `confirm` function will be invoked and how can I return `true` and `false` to the called function

I don't know is there any issue overwriting these functions.

Here is a jsfiddle demo with jquery ( not used fancybox here)

http://jsfiddle.net/fzTa3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will have to change your workflow since the Fancybox version of confirm is not modal dialog (it does not pause script execution). You have to use callbacks to be invoked on corresponding button clicks:

```
window.confirm = function(message, onYes, onNo) {
    $("#confirm_message_box .warmsg span").html(message);
    $.fancybox({
        href: '#confirm_message_box'
        afterLoad: function() {
            this.inner.find('.btn-yes').click(onYes);
            this.inner.find('.btn-no').click(onNo);
        }
    });
}
```

You need to bind `onYes` function to <kbd>Yes</kbd> button and `onNo` to <kbd>No</kbd> in your fancybox initialization.

And the usage would be like this:

```
confirm('Are you sure?', function() {
    // he is sure
}, function() {
    // cancel something
});
```

Comment: thats cuuul idea.. could you please explain, how can i call callback methods. In this case I am using same button for all "Yes" "No"

Comment: See my edit, how you could bind your callback functions to the buttons.

Comment: could you please re-write it ? http://jsfiddle.net/fzTa3/  not used fancybox here

Comment: how you are going to hide the confirm box.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Not to disagree with [@dfsq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15378672/692942) but I find the Yes, No callbacks approach too restrictive while working on this myself found a more flexible way to approach this.

*Example usage:*

```
confirm("Do you wish to continue?", 
    {
        /* 
        Define your buttons here, can handle multiple buttons 
        with custom title and values
        */
        buttons: [
            { class: "yes", type: "button", title: "Yes", value: "yes" },
            { class: "no", type: "button", title: "No", value: "no" },
            { class: "maybe", type: "button", title: "Maybe?", value: "maybe" }
        ],
        modal: true
    }, 
    function(resp) {
        alert("You clicked " + resp);
    }
);
```

- [Answer to Javascript/Jquery Callback for Fancybox Yes No Confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659981/692942)
- Classic Yes, No - <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lankymart/zLBNH/)</kbd>
- Less generic example <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lankymart/zLBNH/9/)</kbd>